# Android BLE Host to controller timeout 0x22

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

On android device facing this LMP_Connection_Timeout (Error code : 0x22 or 34) issue. While checking the HCI logs below are the finding.

1. Android connects to the peripheral.
2. Peripheral sends the "Connection Parameter Update Request" (0x12)
3. Android respond back with parameter accepted. (0x13)
4. Now on the android "Host" send command "LE Connection Update" (0x2013) to the "Controller"
5. There is no command complete from "Controller"to "Host" for this command within 40 seconds. Due to this android drops the connection with error 0x22 (LL Response Timeout)

This issue is happening very randomly and at very high frequnency. Any idea what is causing it and how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe your peripheral never responds with any LL_CONNECTION_PARAM_RSP? You could use an air sniffer to find out. Or check the hci log at the peripheral. If you see a LE Remote Connection Parameter Request sent by the controller, the host shall respond with LE Remote Connection Parameter Request Reply. But this procedure should only be used when supported by both devices, otherwise the L2CAP parameter update request packet should be used instead, so not sure.

Comment: Request originated from the peripheral for which master (Android Phone) responded back paramter accepted. Post this on master host send the command to controller for which controller responds back after 40 sec which is LL timeout.

Comment: Please use an air sniffer to check what's going on then if you don't see anything in the hci log on the peripheral.

Comment: Peripheral received the "Rcvd Connection Parameter Update Response (Accepted)" as it should have. Issue I am assuming is going on HCI layer. Somehow controller fail to respond back to host within timeout and causing disconnect. How can we debug whats going on the controller side.

Comment: It could be an issue with the link layer, and to debug that you need to use an air sniffer. Nothing seems to be wrong with the hci layer on your central. It would also be good if you could upload your hci log, including everything from controller reset.

Comment: @Emil  [Peripheral HCI Logs](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AslWqF_-PVocbraqtyL7VWqim6s?e=cKEpvd)
If you using the wireshark use this filter **bthci_cmd or btl2cap or btatt or not bthci_evt.le_meta_subevent or bthci_evt.le_meta_subevent != 2
and frame.number < 136603 and frame.number > 122482** to see only failure session

Comment: [Master HCI Logs](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AslWqF_-PVocbxTgL6yEOhWfF8c?e=albEtN)
Use filter **frame.number > 635 and frame.number < 1866**

Answer (score 0):

According to the master HCI log file, it's actually the LE Read Remote Features command that times out. Since it's only allowed for the Link Layer to have one outstanding initiated operation, the LE Connection Update request is put in a queue and will be started once the previous operation completes.

Obviously one of the two firmwares has a bug when handling the LE Read Remote Features operation. The HCI logs can't tell which device has the bug. An Air Sniffer that could sniff the Link Layer would tell which one that is misbehaving.

In any case, unrelated to the actual issue, both your devices support the "Connection Parameters Request Procedure" by looking at the LE Supported Features. Therefore, your slave device should not send L2CAP Connection Parameter Update Requests. Instead it can directly send an LE Connection Update command.